# For loop inside the Switch-Case - Java

Tags: java, processing

I want to determine some port writings for area1, area2, and so on.

```
  void controlEvent(CallbackEvent event) {
  if (event.getAction() == ControlP5.ACTION_CLICK) {
    for (int i=1; i<13; i++){
      switch(event.getController().getName()) {  
        case "Area" + str(i):
          println("Button" + i + " Pressed");
          if (port != null) port.write(i + "\n");
          break;}
    }
  }
}
```

But I got *"case expressions must be constant expressions"* error. Is there a way to use a for loop in switch-case? If not, what would be the most logical way to rewrite the codes above?

Comment: can you try  `if(){...}else if(){...}`

Comment: You cannot use dynamic resource to index switch cases. If your code snippet is all there is, you don't need the switch statement at all. Just pass the parameter to whatever operation you want to do or use it to call a separate function where you can process the data.

Comment: How about just `if(event.getController().getName().equals("Area" + str(i))) {println("Button" + i + " Pressed"); if (port != null) port.write(i + "\n");}` ?

Comment: Use some regex so that you do not even need to use a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem list in:

```
case "Area" + str(i):
```

As it is mentioned switch expects constants only, so the value must be known in compilation time, not dynamic. So

```
case "Area1":
case "Area2":
... etc
```

If you want to be more dynamic, then use either if and else-if statements;

```
void controlEvent(CallbackEvent event) {
   if (event.getAction() == ControlP5.ACTION_CLICK) {
   for (int i=1; i<13; i++){ 
      final String controlName = event.getController().getName();
      if(controlName.equals("Area" + str(i))){
         println("Button" + i + " Pressed");
         if (port != null) {
           port.write(i + "\n");
         }
         break;
      } 
   ...
}}}
```

It is a good idea to normalize the action name and extract blocks of code. Having 13 switch cases of if-else statements can be hard to read, so it would be nice to extract method to handle each `ControlP5` or `conrtolName`

Second approach (a little bit too complex maybe, but still):
Create a map of actions:

```
Map<String, Consumer<Integer>> actionMap = new HashMap<>();
actionMap.put("Area1", i ->{
    println("Button" + i + " Pressed");
    if (port != null) {
        port.write(i + "\n");
    }
});
actionMap.put("Area2", i ->{
    println("Button" + i + " Pressed");
    ...
});
.. etc
```

Now you can check if your action map holds desired controlName:

```
      void controlEvent(CallbackEvent event) {
         if (event.getAction() == ControlP5.ACTION_CLICK) {
            final String controlName = event.getController().getName();
            if(actionMap.hasKey(controlName)){
               actionMap.get(controlName).apply(...)
               break;
            }
          }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanations. I want to ask some more: What does ''final'' stands for before defining a string, why do we need it? And I was using ''break'' just for the switch case, should I use it also in if statements that are in a for loop?

Comment: The value must be more than `final`. It must be *constant*, computable at compile time.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out, I have updated my answer. Thank you. Final means that variable value cannot be changed. If you are comparing a single value multiple times it is advised to make it final, so that nothing may change it.